# Retrieve a subset of data with common latest timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with virtual machines data which is filled by some batch job that runs on schedule. Every run (and, correspondingly, the data set) has a unique timestamp. My goal is to retrieve the most fresh data from the table, that is, all records with the latest timestamp. Important note - not the latest record for *each* VMId, but *all* VMIds that have common **and** the latest timestamp.
For simplicity let's consider just 2 columns - 'VMid', 'datetime'.
Which is the most efficient/idiomatic way to do it in PostgreSQL?
Thanks in advance.

**upd**.:
I managed to get the latest timestamp with

```sql
select
    datetime as last
from
    vmdata
order by
    datetime desc
limit 1
```

now I need to use this as a variable (scalar) in another query (WITH?), but not sure how.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the SQL that you've tried and describe the specific issue that you are facing. Sample data and expected outcome (s editable text) would also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM vmdata
WHERE date(datetime) = (SELECT MAX(date(datetime)) FROM vmdata)
```

Comment: That's what I needed, very concise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But this is not doing what you asked which is find the latest timestamp. Instead this is going to find all records for the latest date and that will cover multiple timestamps assuming you are running more then one batch a day.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The question originally had date(datetime) and that was what my answer was based on. The questioner subsequently updated the question to just use datetime and I’m sure they’re capable of adjusting my answer to suit